# Scilab Xcos, insert a difference equation in Xcos diagram

Tags: differential-equations, scilab, xcos

How can I insert a difference equation in Xcos diagram, like:

y(k+1) = y(k)*[a* sqrt(y(k-1))] + b *y(k-1) ;

?

Thanks, Best Regards

**EDIT**
Finding on Internet I think that the best way to address my problem is use:
[scifunck block](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/scifunc_block_m.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually do something like that:

[image: Xcos screenshot]

where the delay blocks are set to the sample time of your model (I assume we are dealing with discrete signals here) and appropriate initial conditions. Make sure to choose a discrete solver and use the same (appropriate for your problem) sample time for the model and the delay blocks.

Comment: Oh .. thanks you.. Your question work.
However, I  found another solution.
I used scifunc_block_m , here to see futher details http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/scifunc_block_m.html